# How do I INSERT the contents of a table into another, but excluding their Primary Key (id's)?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to merge contents of two tables into one (sortedArrivals) using the following code: I do not want the Primary Key id's (here called flightShed.id) to be inserted.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO sortedArrivals

                SELECT  flightSched.id,
                        flightSched.timePeriod, 
                        flightSched.depOrArriv, 
                        flightSched.flightNo,
                        flightSched.airline, 
                        flightSched.dest,  
                        flightSched.origin, 
                        flightSched.depature,
                        flightSched.don, 
                        flightSched.arrivalTime,
                        flightSched.status 

                FROM flightSched ";

        if (!$mysqli->query($sql))
          {
            echo $counter . "<br>" ;
            die('Error: ' . $mysqli->error);

          }
```

However I would like a incrementing Primary Key. When I try inserting the contents of the next table I get: the following error message:

Error: Duplicate entry '9' for key 'PRIMARY'

how do i achieve this?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a view instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name the columns you want to insert into

```
INSERT INTO sortedArrivals (timePeriod, depOrArriv, flightNo, airline, 
                            dest, origin, depature, don, arrivalTime, status)
SELECT timePeriod, 
       depOrArriv, 
       flightNo,
       airline, 
       dest,  
       origin, 
       depature,
       don, 
       arrivalTime,
       status     
FROM flightSched
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this has been bothering me for days.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want the Primary Key id's (here called flightShed.id) to be inserted.

Well then *don’t* select them …

> However I would like a incrementing Primary Key.

… but select just `NULL` instead in their place; a NULL value for an autoindex column will automatically increase the ai counter.

Comment: Instead of selecting the value from the column `flightSched.id`, just select `NULL` …